# ExtJS 5 groups following order in grid store

Tags: sorting, extjs, grouping, user-experience, extjs5

Good day! I am grouping data in my grid store using Ext.util.Grouper, but groups are sorted in unacceptable (for my task) way. I need to change sorting algorythm.

My model has fields 'id', 'code' and 'tag'. I try to group records by field 'tag' and sort groups by minimal value of 'code' property in current group.

I tried to solve this problem using groupFn & sortFn in Ext.util.Grouper, but it gave no result :(

Does anybody know, how can this problem be solved?

Comment: You should post some of your code and specify what "no result" exactly means.

Comment: Faced same issue while ago.  I didn't find proper solution, but you may look into `Ext.grid.feature.GroupStore` class too. Guess you can try to sort groups in the method  `processStore` before groups are processed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try trick - create combined field containing code and tag eg. `00001234|C#` where `00001234` is a code, and `C#` is a tag and group by this field. When your codes will be padded with `0` to equal length they will be sorted as expected. Then remove code from group name on `groupHeaderTpl`.

Calculated field example:

```
{
    name: 'group', 
    type: 'string', 
    convert: function (v, rec) {
        var code = rec.get('code');
        code = Array(8 - String(code).length + 1).join('0') + code; // pad code with zeros
        return code + '|' + rec.get('tag');
    },
    depends: ['code', 'tag'] 
}
```

groupHeaderTpl example:

```
groupHeaderTpl: '{[values.name.split(\"|\")[1]]}'
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zn0v4Lpt/1/